# Bug in dateByAddingTimeInterval

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdate, foundation

After going almost crazy searching where my code failed ... I was able to isolated this strange behaviour. Look at what hapens when substracting -200 days

---

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; //now is 2013-07-19

NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];

NSDate *newDate1 = [now  dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*-199];
newDateTmp=[format stringFromDate:newDate1];
NSLog(@"now:%@ newDateTmp:%@",now,newDateTmp);

newDate1 = [now  dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*-200];
newDateTmp=[format stringFromDate:newDate1];
NSLog(@"now:%@ newDateTmp:%@",now,newDateTmp);

newDate1 = [now  dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*-201];
newDateTmp=[format stringFromDate:newDate1];
NSLog(@"now:%@ newDateTmp:%@",now,newDateTmp);

newDate1 = [now  dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*-365];
newDateTmp=[format stringFromDate:newDate1];
NSLog(@"now:%@ newDateTmp:%@",now,newDateTmp);
```

---

logs:

2013-07-19 15:58:46.123 Vendes[2927:907] now:2013-07-19 13:58:46 +0000 newDateTmp:2013-01-01 **// This is OK**

2013-07-19 15:58:46.124 Vendes[2927:907] now:2013-07-19 13:58:46 +0000 newDateTmp:2013-12-31 **// This is INCORRECT!!!! Look at the YEAR**

2013-07-19 15:58:46.125 Vendes[2927:907] now:2013-07-19 13:58:46 +0000 newDateTmp:2012-12-30 **// This is OK**

2013-07-19 15:58:46.127 Vendes[2927:907] now:2013-07-19 13:58:46 +0000 newDateTmp:2012-07-19 **// This is OK**

---

I guess it will hapopen also tomorrow substracting 201 .. ?? :)

Any idea?

Thks

PS. I solved it using

```
NSDate *newDate1= [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:60*60*daysToAdd sinceDate:now];
```

that works for any daysToAdd value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a bug. The format you use is wrong. It should be

```
@"yyyy-MM-dd"
```

with lower-cased `y`

---

[More information](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns) on upper-cased Y :

> `Y`   -   Year (in "Week of Year" based calendars). This year designation
>   is used in ISO year-week calendar as defined by ISO 8601, but can be
>   used in non-Gregorian based calendar systems where week date
>   processing is desired. **May not always be the same value as calendar
>   year.**

Comment: From Apple's documentation on date formatting: "A common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar. In most cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same number, however they may be different. Typically you should use the calendar year."  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot, I would had never guessed it.